# multiple subpackages for phpdoc

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is it possible to have a file belong to multiple subpackages? For example:

```
/**
 * Name
 *
 * Desc
 *
 * @package    Core
 * @subpackage  Sub1
 * @subpackage  Sub2
 */
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that PHPDoc does not allow you to do it for namespacing reasons. From the [PHPDoc Docs](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.subpackage.pkg.html):

> NOTE: The @subpackage tag is intended to help categorize the elements that are in an actual @package value. Since PHP itself doesn't allow you to have two functions with the same name in the same script, PhpDocumentor also requires all names in an @package to be unique... meaning, @subpackage does not allow further "naming separation" inside that @package. What it does do is allow a level of visual grouping/separation of the elements inside that @package.

It seems that because PHPDoc's @package is a way to pseudo-namespace your functions and classes, but @subpackage is simply for categorization. Have you tried adding more than one subpackage? If so, what were the results?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and it didn't work. I was hoping I was just doing it wrong :)

Oh Well.

Comment: Sorry to be a bummer. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to do this:

```
* @package popcap\system\cache
```

This will create a hierarchy of packages when you compile the PHPdocs.

Answer (score 1):

http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_UML/

Seems to do a pretty good job with multiple @subpackage  tags - it will even generate html- documentation just as phpDocumentor does - though it doesn't seem to be as style-able as phpDocumentor.

It also makes use of the extra subpackage by showing it in the generated UML diagaram.